# positive line bundle from topology viewpoint

Tags: complex-geometry, line-bundles

We know that the existence of positive line bundle is a topological property(more explicitly, it's mertic free).

When the line bundle is induced by a smooth hypersurface $V$ of the projective manifold $M$ with complex dimension $n$, the proof of  Lefschetz hypersurface theorem tell us that the positivity can be viewed as existence of a Morse function with index $\geq n$.

But when the line bundle is induced by
any divisor（even any line bundle）, can we find an analogue topological explaination？

Comment: Why is that a topological property? A complex torus might or might not have a positive line bundle.

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry, my expression is basically same as the book Griffiths and Harris(page 148)，it's may not precise, here I mean this property is mertic-free.